# Change texture color with texture image

Tags: c#, textures

I am doing a slider with custom form and I found a smaple code, the problem is that it uses rectangles with stock colors and I need an image instead.

Here's the part of the code where the textures are drawn:

```
    // Draw the Thumb Object
    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
    {
        if (ThumbFocused)
            brush.Color = Color.Green;
        if (ThumbDragging)
            brush.Color = Color.Gray;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.Thumb);
    }

    //Draw Focus
    if (this.Focused && this.ShowFocusCues)
        ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle);

}
```

I want to use a picture instead of color in this code:

```
brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
```

Ex: `brush = new SolidBrush(PICTURE);`

And on the next ones too.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like the following:

```
Rectangle exampleRectangle = new Rectangle();
exampleRectangle.Width = 75;
exampleRectangle.Height = 75;

// Create an ImageBrush and use it to 
// paint the rectangle.
ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
myBrush.ImageSource = 
    new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"sampleImages\pinkcherries.jpg", UriKind.Relative));

exampleRectangle.Fill = myBrush;
```

Refer to the source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904.aspx

Comment: I think i get it but how do you implement to the code sample i gave above?

Comment: Well, as per your question, you can replace the solid-colored    brush.Color = Color.Green; with the one in my sample that is using bitmap image of your texture.